# Creating an inhouse Firefox addon without an updateURL

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I need to create an addon designed for a few colleagues to automate form entry.  I have been able to edit an example addon and install it to firefox by dragging / dropping the .xpi into the browser.

I am now trying to create the same functionality from scratch, but I am facing errors related to updateURL in the install.rdf file.  I do not own a server, and this addon will never be on the addon market.  Is there anyway I configure my install.rdf so that I do not need this field?  I have read on the mozilla dev guide that this field may be required based on the min / max version elements.  Maybe I can edit these in order to avoid the updateURL 'requirement'?

```
<em:minVersion>2.0</em:minVersion>
<em:maxVersion>3.1b2</em:maxVersion>
```

Answer (score 0):

copy paste this into your install.rdf and update the 3 sctions i tell you too:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!-- This Source Code Form is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public
   - License, v. 2.0. If a copy of the MPL was not distributed with this
   - file, You can obtain one at http://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/. -->
    <RDF xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:em="http://www.mozilla.org/2004/em-rdf#">
      <Description about="urn:mozilla:install-manifest">
        <em:id>user3186636_PUT_YOUR_ADDON_NO_SAPCES_NO_SPECIAL_CHARACTERS_NAME_HERE@jetpack</em:id>
        <em:version>1.2</em:version>
        <em:type>2</em:type>
        <em:bootstrap>true</em:bootstrap>
        <em:unpack>false</em:unpack>

        <!-- Firefox -->
        <em:targetApplication>
          <Description>
            <em:id>{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}</em:id>
            <em:minVersion>26.0</em:minVersion>
            <em:maxVersion>26.0</em:maxVersion>
          </Description>
        </em:targetApplication>

        <!-- Front End MetaData -->
        <em:name>user3186636_PUT_YOUR_ADDON_NAME_HERE</em:name>
        <em:description>user3186636_PUT_YOUR_DESCRIPTION_HERE</em:description>
        <em:creator>Noitidart</em:creator>
      </Description>
    </RDF>
```

here is a demo of how one of my addons isntall.rdf looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!-- This Source Code Form is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public
   - License, v. 2.0. If a copy of the MPL was not distributed with this
   - file, You can obtain one at http://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/. -->
    <RDF xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:em="http://www.mozilla.org/2004/em-rdf#">
      <Description about="urn:mozilla:install-manifest">
        <em:id>loadcontext-and-http-modify-observer@jetpack</em:id>
        <em:version>initial</em:version>
        <em:type>2</em:type>
        <em:bootstrap>true</em:bootstrap>
        <em:unpack>false</em:unpack>

        <!-- Firefox -->
        <em:targetApplication>
          <Description>
            <em:id>{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}</em:id>
            <em:minVersion>26.0</em:minVersion>
            <em:maxVersion>26.0</em:maxVersion>
          </Description>
        </em:targetApplication>

        <!-- Front End MetaData -->
        <em:name>loadcontext and http modify observer</em:name>
        <em:description>ff-research-addon: exploring how loadcontext works, how it can be used to get html and xul windows of http loads</em:description>
        <em:creator>Noitidart</em:creator>
      </Description>
    </RDF>
```